# Как расчититать разницу между двумя датами?

Tags: javascript, php, html

На форму я получаю две даты, мне нужно вычислить разницу между двумя датами и отобразить (например 10 дней, или 1 месяц и 3 дня). Разница между `$task['term']`  и `$task['date_created_solution']`. Поправила код.

```
<td align="center">
    Срок  <input value="{{$task['term']}}">
    <br>
    Дата выполнения
    <input value="{{date('d-m-y', strtotime($task['date_created_solution']))}}">
    <br>
    Количество дней просрочки <input value="{{\Carbon\Carbon::parse($task['term'])->diffForHumans($task['date_created_solution'])}}">
</td>
```

Comment: Для получения разницы лучше использовать встроенные библиотеки и классы DateTime/DateInterval, либо их аналоги из [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-difference) библиотеки.

Answer (score 3):

можно посмотреть в сторону `DateInterval`

```
$start  = new DateTime('now');
$end = new DateTime("2022-12-31");
$interval = $end->diff($start);

print_r([
    'days' => $interval->days,        
]);
```

Answer (score -1):

С помощью этого кода вы можете
это сделать:

```
// Получим разницу между двумя датами
$diff = abs($task['term'] - $task['date_created_solution']); 

// Чтобы получить год, разделим полученную дату на
// количество секунд в году (365*60 *60*24)
$years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24)); 
  

// Чтобы получить месяц, вычтим его с годами и
// делим полученную дату на
// общее количество секунд в месяце (30*60*60*24)
$months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24)
                               / (30*60*60*24)); 
  
  
// Чтобы получить день, вычтем его с годами и
// месяцами и разделим полученную дату на
// количество секунд в днях (60*60*24)
$days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - 
             $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));
  
  
// Чтобы получить час, вычтем его с годами,
// месяцами и секундами и разделим полученную
// дату на количество секунд в часах (60*60)
$hours = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 
       - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24)
                                   / (60*60)); 
  
  
// Чтобы получить минуты, вычтем их с годами,
// месяцами, секундами и часами и разделим
// на итоговую дату в секундах, т.е. 60
$minutes = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 
         - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 
                          - $hours*60*60)/ 60); 
  
  
// Чтобы получить минуты, вычтем их с годами,
// месяцами, секундами, часами и минутами
$seconds = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 
         - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24
                - $hours*60*60 - $minutes*60)); 
//Вывод результата
echo("%d years, %d months, %d days, %d hours, "
     . "%d minutes, %d seconds", $years, $months,
             $days, $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
```

Comment: Как в этом решении учитываются високосные годы?

Comment: Она превращает 2 даты в количество секунд и ищет разницу, поэтому високосные годы учитываются в расчете

Comment: Как-то смущает, что между 15.01.2020 и 15.02.2020 получается 1 месяц и 1 день, между 15.02.2022 и 15.03.2022 - 0 месяцев и 28 дней, а между 01.01.2021 и 31.12.2023 - 1 год, 12 месяцев и 4 дня.

Comment: Вообще не рабочий код, так как не учитывает много нюансов. Для получения разницы лучше использовать встроенные библиотеки и классы DateTime/DateInterval, либо их аналоги из [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) библиотеки.

Comment: Carbon я и использую в работе с датами, а тут не знаю как вычислить разницу с помощью него